# Reading lines from text file to structs C

Tags: c, list, file, text, struct

I am trying to read lines from a list to my structs, and it is almost working. I am not really sure what the problem is, but the last line of the text file wont show up when I call for the structs and I do not think the words are placed right...

```
void loadFile(char fileName[], Song *arr, int nrOf) {

    FILE *input = fopen(fileName, "r");


    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("Error, the file could not load!");
    } else {

        fscanf(input, "%d", &nrOf);
        fscanf(input, "%*[^\n]\n", NULL);

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++) {
            fgets(arr[i].song, sizeof(arr[i].song), input);
            fgets(arr[i].artist, sizeof(arr[i].artist), input);
            fgets(arr[i].year, sizeof(arr[i].year), input);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++) {
            printf("%s", arr[i].song);
            printf("%s", arr[i].artist);
            printf("%s", arr[i].year);
        }
        rewind(input);
        printf("The file is now ready.\n");

    }

    fclose(input);

}
```

The text file starts with a number on the first line to keep track of how many songs there are in the list. I therefore tried with this:

```
fscanf(input, "%d", &nrOf);
fscanf(input, "%*[^\n]\n", NULL);
```

to be able to skip the first line after nrOf got the number.

EDIT:
Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct Song {

char song[20];
char artist[20];
char year[5];

} Song;
```

Here is the text file:

```
4
Mr Tambourine Man
Bob Dylan
1965
Dead Ringer for Love
Meat Loaf
1981
Euphoria
Loreen
2012
Love Me Now
John Legend
2016
```

And the struct is dynamic allocated:

```
Song *arr;
arr = malloc(sizeof(Song));
```

Comment: It might be useful if you would include a small text excerpt or example of the file you are reading from. That would give us (other SO users) an opportunity to see what exactly you are working with so we can better advise you.

Comment: Might be helpful to see definition of `Song`.

Comment: If you want to read lines, read lines (*fgets* is ok for this), then parse them as strings (*sscanf*, *strtok*, plain *for* loop char by char...).

Comment: Also, alwsys check return value of *scanf* functions.

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the code.  why pass in a parameter: `nrOf` and then immediately overlay (the local copy of that parameter) with the line: `fscanf(input, "%d", &nrOf);`   Note: this does not update the callers' variable.

Comment: The posted code has no idea as to how much room is available in the `arr[]` array for song entries.  Strongly suggest the parameter: `nrOf` be used to pass in that information, that the code compare `nrOf` with the read in count to assure there is sufficient room in the array so as to avoid any chance of a buffer overflow

Comment: @hyde and `fgets`, OP doesn't even check errors for that.

Comment: The calls to `fgets()` indicate that there are no delimiters in the input file to separate the fields.  This indicates that each field in the input file is exactly the same length as the fields in the `Song` struct  Is this a true criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a combination of reasons why the last line(s) do not print

The main reason is the last line(s) were never read

Should not call `fclose()` in any execution path where the file failed to open

there is no need to call `rewind()` when the next statement is `fclose()`

Since the calls to `printf()` for the fields in the `Song` array are output, one right after another, this will result in a long long single line output to the terminal,  Hopefully the terminal is set to automatically scroll after so many columns of output, but that cannot be depended upon.

When outputting an error message, it is best to output it to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  The function: `perror()` does that AND also outputs the reason the OS thinks the error occurred.  (it does this by referencing `errno` to select which error message to output.)

the following is the key problem:

if the input file contains one song info per line then the field `year` will either contain a trailing newline or the newline will not have been read.   If the newline was not read, then the next call to `fgets()` which was trying to input the song title will only receive a newline then all following fields (of all songs) will be progressively further off.

Suggest after reading a song fields, use a loop to clear out any remaining characters in the input line, similar to:

```
int ch;
while( (ch = getchar( input )) && EOF != ch && '\n' != ch );
```